# AutoComplete Component KendoUI show this error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I have a problem in [AutoComplete Component `KendoUI`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/filtering/)
I Get data from WebService and initial to list object for data of `AutoComplete`
 
Interface:

```
export interface ItemComboBox {
    text: string,
    value: string
}
```

Component:

```
toolCodeList: Array<ItemComboBox> = [];
toolCodeSource: Array<ItemComboBox> = [];
@ViewChild("toolCode") toolCode;
constructor(...){} 
ngOnInit(){
 this.apiService.getALLToolCode().subscribe(data => {
      this.toolCodeSource = data;    
       console.log(JSON.stringify(this.toolCodeSource));
    }); 
}
handleFilterToolCode(value: any) {    
    this.toolCodeList =this.toolCodeSource.filter((s) => s.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
```

log this.toolCodeSource:

```
[{"text":"111","value":"1"},{"text":"121","value":"2"},{"text":"131","value":"3"},{"text":"141","value":"4"},{"text":"151","value":"5"},{"text":"161","value":"6"},{"text":"171","value":"7"},{"text":"181","value":"8"}
```

HTML:

```
<kendo-autocomplete   
  #toolCode
  [(ngModel)]="requestAttribute.toolCode"                            
  name="toolCode"
  class="form-control" 
  [filterable]="true"                              

    (filterChange)="handleFilterToolCode($event)"
    (blur)="blurToolCode()"
    [data]="toolCodeList">                                  
</kendo-autocomplete>
```

Service:

```
getALLToolCode():Observable<ItemComboBox[]> {
const header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
return this.http
  .get<ItemComboBox[]>(`${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/Request/GetALLToolCode`)
  .map(response => response || {})
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When I type a word in AutoComplete element show me this error in the console browser.

> RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

How can I solve this problem?Tanks

Comment: what event is given when the filterChange is fired?

Comment: do you have data in this.toolCodeSource? can you log it?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi **filterChange** is an event. Fires each time the user types in the input field. user can filter the source based on the passed filtration value.

Comment: @fatemefazli Yes **this.toolCodeSource** has a lot of value

Comment: @fatemefazli this problem for this line **this.toolCodeSource.filter((s) => s.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);** Is it true filtering?

Answer (score -1):

because you are using object array not string array for data but the autocomplete needs string array you should map it to string:

```
handleFilter(value) {
     this.data = this.source.map(item => item.text).filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);}
}
```

and `[data]="data"` in  ui.
hope this works.

Comment: It doesnn't need **map**.beacuse **toolCodeList** has declare by ItemComboBox Array.and ItemComboBox has text field

Comment: it need map because the array you give to data should be string array in your code you are giving object array to [data].

Comment: In Kendo UI AutoCompleteComponent When the component is bound to complex data (objects), define valueField. The valueField input has to point to a property of type string. As a result, the AutoComplete extracts the input from the selected data item and in this way sets the value of the component. [see this example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/data-binding/#toc-arrays-of-complex-data)

Comment: I solve it, ، The problem for data webservice one of them **text** value was null